# Закрытие BroadcastReceiver после закрытия приложения

Tags: android, java

Проблема в том, что BroadcastReceiver продолжает дальше работать при закрытии приложения. Нужно чтобы он убивался вместе с финишем программы.

```
BroadcastReceiver.abortBroadcast() // Не работает
```

Comment: Зачем тогда его создавать? Слушатель/Сервис нужен как раз, что бы отлавливаться какие либо события связанные с вашим приложением, в тот момент когда приложение закрыто

Comment: ну так регистрируй его в методах onCreate и снимай при закрытии программы(учитывай что при повороте экрана onCreate и destroy тоже вызываются, поэтому придумай что нибудь. например рега в сервисе).
а не в манифесте.